# Is it possible to have a screen that shows a message instead of a list when no dropdown option is selected in Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I have a dropdown select in my Blazor page where a user may select a car brand from a dropdown list. Based on their selection, it will display a list of data as per brand selected. Currently if no option is select and the page loads, all the data is shown for all cars. I want it such that a message could show to say, "choose a brand to show records" so that only when a brand is picked, records will show. I am new to Blazor, please excuse me if there is anything missing, I will add it.

my code:

```
 <MudSelect @bind-Value="@selectedBrand" Label="Select Brand" Variant="Variant.Filled">
            @foreach (var item in brand) {
                <MudSelectItem Value="@item.Id">@item.Description</MudSelectItem>
            }
  </MudSelect>
<MudTable Items="FilterBrand" Hover="true" Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Sm" Loading="@_loading" LoadingProgressColor="Color.Info">
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh>Brandn</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Model</MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Nr">@context.Brandname</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Sign">@context.Model</MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
</MudTable>
@code{
  private List<CarViewModel> cars= new List<CarViewModel>();
private List<Brand> brand = new List<Brand>();
    private string selectedBrand;
    private List<CarViewModel> FilterBrand => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedBrand)
        ? cars.Where(s => s.Brandname == selectedBrand).ToList()
        : cars;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
        await Task.Delay(0);

        cars= GetCars();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very straight forward:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedBrand)
{
  <MudTable Items="FilterBrand" ... > ... </MudTable>
}
else
{
   <p>"choose a brand to show records"</p>
}
```